# Dev Express Winform Gridview Session Binding

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

This is the below solution using i am binding datasource. but `tblData1` may change at runtime.
Fields in `tblData1` can be increase or decrease at run time so how can i refresh the gridview with new structure of the class.

```
 XPInstantFeedbackSource instantDS = new XPInstantFeedbackSource(typeof(tblData1));
 instantDS.ResolveSession += instantDS_ResolveSession;
 instantDS.DismissSession += instantDS_DismissSession;
 gridView1.GridControl.DataSource = instantDS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
gridView1.GridControl.RefreshDataSource();
```

Comment: please dont answer if question is not clear to you !

Comment: Well, that's not a nice way to ask for help-

Comment: hey Marko.. actually i needed the solution desperately but i was not getting it from anywhere that might forced me talk like this.

but anyhow i got the solution now. Thanks